# Проектирование тетриса

Tags: java, разработка-игр, архитектура

Пишу очередной тетрис, просто для себя. После Мартина и Макконела хочется простой и красивой архитектуры. До некоторого момента все удавалось, но начали выползать костыли.

Есть следующий упрощенный кусок архитектуры:

1. Фигура на поле:

   ```
   class Figure{
       List<Shape> shapes;
       Shape currentShape;
   }
   ```
2. Форма фигуры:

   ```
   class Shape{
       private int[][] model;
   }
   ```

Нужен класс, который создает различные фигуры («T», «J», «L» и прочие).
Пока фантазии хватило только на это:

```
public class FigureFactory {

    private static List< Figure > figures = init();

    private static List< Figure > init() {
        ArrayList< Figure > figures = new ArrayList<>();
        Figure J = null, L = null, O = null, S = null, T = null, Z = null;

        J = new Figure( new Position( 0, 0 ), new ArrayList< Figure.Shape >() {{
            add( new Figure.Shape( new int[][]{ { 0, 1 }, { 0, 1 }, { 1, 1 } } ) );
            add( new Figure.Shape( new int[][]{ { 1, 0, 0 }, { 1, 1, 1 }, } ) );
            add( new Figure.Shape( new int[][]{ { 1, 1 }, { 1, 0 }, { 1, 0 } } ) );
            add( new Figure.Shape( new int[][]{ { 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 1 }, } ) );
        }} );

        ...

        return Arrays.asList( J, L, O, S, T, Z );
    }

    public static Figure getJ() {
        return figures.get( 0 );
    }

    public static Figure getL() {
        return figures.get( 1 );
    }

    ...

    public static Figure getRandomFigure() {
        return figures.get( ( (int) ( Math.random() * figures.size() ) ) );
}
```

Проблемы и вопросы следующие:

- *Название класса.* Суффикс `Factory`, как подсказывает гугл, применяется при использовании паттерна «Абстрактная фабрика», а здесь его явно нет. Какое лучше всего подойдет? `Builder` не подходит по той же причине. Есть еще какой-то паттерн для подобного?
- *Иммутабельность.* Основная проблема — `Figure` не неизменяемый (immutable), так как нужно переключать текущие состояния (`Shape`), поворачивая фигуру. Сейчас каждый последующий вызов `getL()` возвращает ссылку на один и тот же объект, изменение которого испортит его для последующих вызовов. Можно переместить вытащить создание каждой конкретной фигуры из `init()` в `getL()`/`getlJ()` и возвращать новые объекты, но когда тогда быть с `getRandomFigure()`? Нужен метод, возвращающий любую случайную фигуру из всех возможных, но без списка возможных не понятно, как это сделать. Хотелось бы без рефлексии. Вопрос не в том, как сделать, чтобы работало, а как сделать красиво и аккуратно.
- Резонно ли здесь *применить наследование*, реализовав группу классов наподобие `JFigure`, `TFigure`, `LFigure` и спрятав всё создание туда?

Буду благодарен за любые ссылки\книжки и особенно за критику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, названия не так уж и важны для правильной архитектуры. Есть ли в вашей фабрике суффикс Factory или нет — не так уж и важно.

Теперь по поводу того, что у вас уже есть.

```
class Figure{
    List<Shape> shapes;
    Shape currentShape;
}
```

Это плохо. Вы описываете тут не одну фигуру, а все, которые есть на поле. Так что это `class Board` или там `class Arena`.

Затем, фигуры, которые уже упали. Вам не нужно знать исходные фигуры, ведь они ушли из игры. Кроме того, из них могут быть удалены клетки, когда строка заполняется и удаляется. Значит, вам нужна только одна — текущая — фигура (и возможно следующая фигура для подсказки). А для остального вам нужен список полей, признак того, занято или нет каждое из полей, и возможно цвет поля, если хотите назначить разные цвета разным фигурам.

Далее, фигура. Фигура не иммутабельна! Она движется по полю и поворачивается! А вот её форма иммутабельна. Значит, у нас появляются классы `Shape` (иммутабельная форма) и `Figure` (раз мы уж переименовали старый класс `Figure` в `Board`), который содержит `Shape`, его ориентацию и позицию. И умеет, понятно, выдать список своих клеток.

Затем, вам нужна логика игры. Которая определяет, что на каждом тике фигура едет вниз, поворачивается по команде (с проверкой возможности), и при достижении занятых клеток распадается на <s>плесень и липовый мёд</s> занятые клетки того же цвета, что и исходная фигура. И ещё, логика пытается разместить новую фигуру, а если не может, конец игры.

Затем, нужен генератор фигур, который выдаёт по просьбе новую фигуру.

Ну и ввод от пользователя и UI, без этого даже в тетрисе никак.

---

Окей, уточнение в комментарии говорит, что `Figure` таки описывает фигуру. Тогда, как мне кажется, иметь внутри список `Shape`'ов совершенно не нужно. Пусть фигура знает список своих клеток. Тогда у нас не нужны типы фигур. Получаем простую фабрику фигур:

```
class Rotation {
    public rotateAbout(Point origin, Point what) {
        int dx = k11 * (what.X - origin.X) + k12 * (what.Y - origin.Y);
        int dy = k21 * (what.X - origin.X) + k22 * (what.Y - origin.Y);
        return new Point(origin.X + dx, origin.Y + dy);
    }

    static public Rotation Identity() { return new Orientation(1, 0, 0, 1); }
    static public Rotation Next() { return new Orientation(k12, -k11, k22, -k21); }
    static public Rotation Prev() { return new Orientation(-k12, k11, -k22, k21); }
}

class Shape {
    public Collection<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}

class Figure {
    Rotation rotation;
    Vector locationOffset;
    final Shape shape;

    public Collection<Point> getPoints() {
        ArrayList<Point> result = new ArrayList<Point>();
        for (Point p : shape.getPoints()) {
            Point rotated = rotation.rotateAbout(shape.Origin, p);
            Point shifted = rotated.add(locationOffset);
            result.add(shifted);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и теперь

```
static class ShapeFactory {

    final Collection<Point> lPoints =
        new ArrayList<Point>() {
            new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 1), new Point(0, 2), new Point(1, 2)
        };

    final Shape L = new Shape(lPoints);
    public Shape getL() {
        return L;
    }

    final ArrayList<Shape> allShapes = new ArrayList<Shape>() {
        L, S, // ну и все остальные
    }

    public Shape getRandom() {
        int index = random.nextInt(allShapes.length);
        return allShapes[index];
    }
}
```

Таким образом, у вас иммутабельный `Shape` и мутабельный `Figure`.

---

Наследование `Shape`'ов (и тем более фигур) мне кажется овердизайном, вам-то всего-навсего данные виртуализировать надо.

Comment: Вы немного не поняли, текущий Figure содержит именно список имутабельных форм (Shape), а не все фигуры на поле. Поле вообще отдельным классом и там все в порядке :) Каждая такая форма - разная ориентация одной фигуры. У фигуры О, например, всего 1 форма, а у I - две (горизонтальная и вертикальная). Логика самой игры не сложна и тоже практически готова. А про генератор я и спрашивал :)

Comment: @Slavuti4: Окей, дополнил ответ (ещё).